# How to run a job in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, jobs

I'm writing an application ASP.NET MVC. I have some people records that expire after 2 year (their Status field changes to expired). I need to run a check daily to check for expired records.  I do not have permission to create a job on the database, so i need to find a way to do it on my application.

Is there something equivalent to the database job or a workaround to let this run daily without any user intervention and without blocking the application ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please take a look at Quartz. I've used it in several projects to solve these kind of problems.

http://www.quartz-scheduler.net/

Answer (score 2):

Nice article about Background Jobs in ASP.NET
http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToRunBackgroundTasksInASPNET.aspx

I really like HANGFIRE. Which is really easy to use and has nice front end for managing tasks.

Answer (score 1):

You must be logged on as an administrator to perform these steps. If you aren't logged on as an administrator, you can only change settings that apply to your user account.

If you use a specific program on a regular basis, you can use the Task Scheduler wizard to create a task that opens the program for you automatically according to the schedule you choose.

1. Open Task Scheduler by clicking the Start button  , clicking Control Panel, clicking System and Security, clicking Administrative Tools, and then double-clicking Task Scheduler.   If you're prompted for an administrator password or confirmation, type the password or provide confirmation.
2. Click the Action menu, and then click Create Basic Task.
3. Type a name for the task and an optional description, and then click Next.
4. Do one of the following:

•   To select a schedule based on the calendar, click Daily, Weekly, Monthly, or One time, click Next; specify the schedule you want to use, and then click Next.

•   To select a schedule based on common recurring events, click When the computer starts or When I log on, and then click Next.

•   To select a schedule based on specific events, click When a specific event is logged, click Next; specify the event log and other information using the drop-down lists, and then click Next.

5. To schedule a program to start automatically, click Start a program, and then click Next.
6. Click Browse to find the program you want to start, and then click Next.
7. Click Finish.

[Reference](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-in/windows/schedule-task#1TC=windows-7)

Comment: I think this won't work for me as i need the job to update fields within my database.